# Duplicate frames in wireshark PcapdotNet

Tags: c#, tcp, wireshark, winpcap, pcapdotnet

I have created a whole TCP/IP stack using Pcapdotnet and c#. 
But in some PCs wire-shark shows duplicate frames for all the packets send with the Pcapdotnet. Please see the screenshot

[image]

Here Frame no.s 303, 306 and 308 are sent using pcapdotnet and 304,307 and 309 are the respective duplicates.
These duplicate frames are not reaching the destination or on the network. 
This issues are only observed in some Windows PCs.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I suspect that you are using the wrong sequence numbers. You can examine them in wireshark.

Comment: See relevant discussion in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pcapdotnet/P9JMZr0J-Ko

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered a very similar issue with PcapDotNet. It also was visible that it happens on certain machines, while on others it didn't.

The problem was that both WinPcap and Npcap were installed on some of my machines (since I had Wireshark 2 installed before upgrading to Wireshark 3, like most users). The procedure to solve it was:

1. Uninstall WinPcap
2. Uninstall Npcap
3. Re-install Npcap, preferably the latest release (today it's 0.998). Be sure to select the "WinPcap Compatibility" option in the installer.

This completely solved the issue for me.
I know it's been a while since the question was posted, but I guess it's still relevant to some people.